# Multiple partials inside a content_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have various 'sidebar modules' in different partials so that different layouts, etc. can have different sidebar modules. So I have this in my layout file:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <%= yield :sidebar %>
</div>
```

and in different views I use:

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
    <% render :partial => '/sidebar_modules/allergy_season' %>
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly fine, as expected. Unfortunately, I'm unable to render multiple partials this way. For instance:

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
    <% render :partial => '/sidebar_modules/allergy_season' %>
    <% render :partial => '/sidebar_modules/resolution_rate' %>
<% end %>
```

will not work. It will just render the last one.

What would be the easiest/cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `<%=` instead of `<%`

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <%= render :partial => '/sidebar_modules/allergy_season' %>
  <%= render :partial => '/sidebar_modules/resolution_rate' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hahaha I can't believe it was something as simple as that. Thanks!